# What URLs must be in IE's Trusted Sites list to allow Windows Update?

Tags: windows, group-policy, internet-explorer

Particularly for servers in which [IE Enhanced Security Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd883248%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is enabled, you need to have all the Windows Update/Microsoft Update URLs in your "Trusted Sites" list in order to use the site.

(Furthermore, for domain member servers where Group Policy enforces Internet Explorer's list of "Trusted Sites", you don't have the option to edit the Trusted Sites yourself... so *all* the necessary URLs should be listed in the GPO.)

**So, what is the full list of URLs I'll need in IE's Trusted Sites?** So far I have the following:

- http(s)://*.update.microsoft.com
- http://download.windowsupdate.com
- http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com

I seem to remember there being several more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little more digging and found the following.

From [KB836941](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941#MT9) that @joequerty found:

- `http://*update.microsoft.com`
- `https://*update.microsoft.com`
- `http://download.windowsupdate.com`

From [an MS MVP's WSUS blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/athif/pages/43174.aspx):

- `http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com`
- `http://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com`
- `https://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com`
- `http://download.windowsupdate.com`
- `http://*.download.windowsupdate.com`
- `http://*.windowsupdate.com`
- `http://wustat.windows.com`
- `http://ntservicepack.microsoft.com`

Not required for Windows Update, but could also be useful:

- `http://office.microsoft.com/officeupdate`

Combined with [the wildcard rules in KB184456](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184456), I get the following:

- `*://*update.microsoft.com`
- `*://*.windowsupdate.com`
- `http://wustat.windows.com`
- `http://ntservicepack.microsoft.com`
- `http://office.microsoft.com`

Hope that helps someone out there!

Answer (score 9):

[KB836941](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941#MT9) suggests these addresses:

```
http://*update.microsoft.com

https://*update.microsoft.com

http://download.windowsupdate.com
```

Better still:

```
http://*.microsoft.com
http://*.windowsupdate.com
```

Comment: Ah, `*update.microsoft.com` instead of `*.update.microsoft.com`, which covers the http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com case as well as http://update.microsoft.com. Looks good to me, but I remember having to program more than these into UTM firewalls to keep them from messing with the traffic...?

Comment: Yah - except IE9 won't accept anything in the form *alphanum, it requires a dot between "*" and "alphanum" This is from the error message:- You have entered an invalid wildcard sequence. Examples of valid patterns: *://*.microsoft.com http://*.microsoft.co.jp Examples of invalid patterns: http://microsoft.*.com ftp://*

Comment: Interesting. On Server 2008R2, I removed all trusted zones and then added the two 'better still' ones you recommend. It took *.microsoft.com but would not take *.windowsupdate.com, stating in a message box that it was already in the trusted zone (but I don't see it which is also strange!)

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy:

http://*.microsoft.com
http://*.windowsupdate.com

Repeat above with https.

Comment: Are you sure ???

Answer (score -1):

Even better:

```
*://*.microsoft.com
*://*.windowsupdate.com
*://*.windows.com
```